# Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php

Estou tentando listar uma tabela do banco de dados porem não estou tendo sucesso e recebendo o error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\service_desk_pi\classes\Model.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\service_desk_pi\equipamento.php(7): Model->listar() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\service_desk_pi\classes\Model.php on line 28"

Model.php

```
<?php
require 'Conexao.php';
class Model
{

    protected $tabela;
    protected $class;
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $conexao = new Conexao();
        $this->db = $conexao->conectar();
    }

    public function inserir($values)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->tabela} VALUES ($values)";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->db->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function listar()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tabela}";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->class);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tabela} WHERE id = {$id}";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->class);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

    public function alterar($id, $values)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE {$this->tabela} SET {$values} WHERE id = {$id}";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    public function deletar($id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM {$this->tabela} WHERE id = {$id}";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Conexao.php

```
<?php

class Conexao
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
    }

    public function conectar() {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO(
                            $this->host,
                            $this->user, 
                            $this->password
                        );

            return $conn;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Erro na conexao. Erro reportado: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

EquipamentoDAO.php

```
<?php
require 'Model.php';
class EquipamentoDAO extends Model
{   
    public function __construct() {
        $this->tabela = 'equipamento';
        $this->class = 'Equipamento';
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php include 'layout/header.php'; 
?>
<?php 
require 'classes/Equipamento.php';
require 'classes/EquipamentoDAO.php';
$equipamentoDAO = new EquipamentoDAO();
$equipamentos = $equipamentoDAO->listar();


?>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:40px">
   <div class="col-10">
       <h2>Gerenciar equipamentos</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
       <a href="form_equipamento.php" class="btn btn-success">Nova</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>#ID</th>
               <th>id_chamado</th>
               <th>Marca</th>
               <th>Modelo</th>
               <th>Categoria</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <?php foreach($equipamentos as $equipamento){ ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?= $equipamento->getId() ?></td>
               <td><?= $equipamento->getMarca() ?></td>
               <td>
                   <a href="form_equipamento.php?id=<?= $equipamento->getId() ?>">Editar</a> | 
                   <a href="controle_equipamento.php?acao=deletar&id=<?= $equipamento->getId() ?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?')">Excluir</a>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>

<?php include 'layout/footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que, como você declarou um construtor na classe EquipamentoDAO, o construtor da classe Model não será executado automaticamente.

Se você adicionar o código abaixo no construtor da classe EquipamentoDAO o seu problema deve ser resolvido

```
parent::__construct();
```

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado.